# Show contact form in a pop-up window with Bootstrap classes

Tags: 8

Can you please tell us how to create a modal window with a contact form, with the bootstrap classes?

I open the form with

```
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-options="{ &quot;width&quot;:633 }" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/node">Open form</a>
```

And why is the modal window not working for anonyms? Thank you!

**UPD**

Happened!

Connected via theme, at the root of the theme there is a file **my-theme.libraries.yml** in it, we develop a library

```
drupal.dialog.ajax:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    /core/misc/dialog/dialog.ajax.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/drupal.dialog
```

Followed by the root theme in the file **my-theme.theme** Insert function

```
function my-theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'my-theme/drupal.dialog.ajax';
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to copy this from core.libraries.yml into your theme. You can attach the core library directly: `$variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap and Ajax are two different methods for modal dialogs.

If you want to open a popup with Bootstrap this would be client side. This means you deliver the form embedded in the page as a block and hide it by wrapping it in a Bootstrap modal container:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/

If you want to load a modal with Drupal Ajax, then use the link you've provided in the question, but target the url of the form, not that of the frontpage:

```
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/contact">Open form</a>
```

For this to work you have to attach a js library:

```
$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
```

> And why is the modal window not working for anonyms?

It works for logged in users without attaching the library, because core code is doing this already for the admin dialogs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

If I understand correctly, this code can be connected via its module or theme.

$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';

I can not understand how the library file is connected drupal.dialog.ajax' It must be created at core/drupal.dialog.ajax?