# Ajax modal does not show for authenticated users

Tags: 8, ajax

I'm testing a simple ajax modal link on a Drupal site and figured out that the modal

```
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/search/node">Search</a>
```

does only show when logged in as admin. For authenticated users it does not load (it just shows the search page). This is independent of the underlying theme I am using (bartik or a bootstrap subtheme). No error messages or status-reports give any indication what's going on. I thought only for anonymous users ajax needs to be added for the theme dependencies ? What am I missing here ?

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238591/show-contact-form-in-a-pop-up-window-with-bootstrap-classes, which was for anonymous users, but an additional question was, why it *is* working for an authenticated user and in this case the authenticated user already had the library loaded for other modal dialogs. For your authenticated user it *is not* working at the moment, so you have to add the library, which btw. is always the correct thing to do, because you don't know if the other functionality which is using the library already will stay in place.

Answer (score 1):

For `use-ajax` to work for Anonymous as well as Authenticated user, Core `core/drupal.ajax` library must need to be loaded on page, where we're using 'use-ajax' class.

You can include this library with either using `#attached` in your *Form* or *Controller* or you can implement [`hook_page_attachments`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.3.x) hook and attach ajax library.

If you're trying to add link to text inside your form, you can directly use `#ajax` instead of using classes as per directed in [Ajax commands for opening and closing Dialogs and generic Dialog Controller added to core](https://www.drupal.org/node/1989646)

```
  $form['link'] = [
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => 'Link 1 (modal)',
    '#url' => Url::fromRoute('ajax_test.dialog_contents'),
    '#ajax' => [
      'dialogType' => 'modal',
    ],
  ];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, just using #attached or using #ajax in the form did not solve my current problem. Adding the dependency to my theme did, as suggested by 4k4. However, using hook_page_attachments() sounds helpful as well, I did not know this before.

Comment: Normally you don't need this hook. Ideally the code which adds the modal link also adds the library. For example if you add the link to $build in a controller, then also attach the library to this build array `$build['#attached']`. Forms, blocks, field formatters etc. do the same. Then Drupal can render all parts of the website and the attachments from each element bubble up to the page. So each page loads only the libraries necessary for the specific content.